# How to Disable this save/submit button?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor

I am wondering what is the best method to disable this save button after one click?

Here is the code :

```
<button data-bind="enable: !$root.isSaving(), click: $root.addNewCard.bind($data, $root)" class="primary button" role="button" data-size="sm">
                                Save
                                </button>
```

Above is the .cshtml code

Below is the javascript code:

```
BillingInformation.prototype.addNewCard = function (parent, creditCard) {
parent.isSaving(true);
parent.isSettingDefault(true);

creditCard.cardNumber(creditCard.cardNumber().replace(/-|\s/g, ''));

let $form = $('#addNewCardForm' + creditCard.walletItemId()),
    cardNumber = creditCard.cardNumber();

parseDynamicFormElements($form);

if ($form.valid()) {
    verifyAddress($form, function () {
        authentication.checkReAuthenticatedThenLaunchLoginOrExecuteTask(() => {
            creditCard
                .save()
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status === HTTP_STATUS_OK) {
                        creditCard.walletItemId(response.content);
                        parent.walletItems.push(creditCard);
                        creditCard.lastFourDigits(
                            creditCard.cardNumber() ? creditCard.cardNumber().substr(-4) : ''
                        );
                        creditCard.obfuscatedCardNumber(cardNumber.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, '*'));
                        parent.newCardInstance(new CreditCard({paymentType: 'creditCards'}));
                        checkForRedirect();
                    } else {
                        let container = document.createElement('div');
                        container.append(
                            'We were unable to save your payment information. Please try again or give us a call at 1-800-461-8898'
                        );
                        smartPak.ui.modal(container, {
                            title: 'Unable to Save Payment Method',
                            buttons: {
                                Close: function (modal) {
                                    modal.close();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    parent.isSaving(false);
                });
        });
    });
    parent.isSaving(false);
} else {
    parent.isSaving(false);
    parent.isSettingDefault(false);
}
```

};

What is the best method to prevent this from being clicked more than once after submission? currently if clicked multiple times it will duplicate the cc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the the enable property should bind to a variable, not a function like you do in

```
enable: !$root.isSaving()
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try switching click:

`$root.addNewCard.bind($data, $root)` to click: `$root.addNewCard.bind($root, $data) ?`

according to your declaration:

```
BillingInformation.prototype.addNewCard = function (parent, creditCard) 
creditCard = $data from the form and parent = $root ?
```